# How to dispose of a GMap instance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a program that use GMap. The GMap is in instance X(to give exemple). Instance X is called after a login. I can logout of X and start again the login process.
The problem is that instance X never get released. I really thing that I have pinpointed the problem to the GMap, because right now I remove everything else that it loaded.

I tried to do this when I logout:

```
gmap.Manager.CancelTileCaching();
gmap.Dispose();
gmap = null;
```

I also remove the control itself from the xaml code with a

```
grid.Children.Remove(myMap)
```

Comment: Why do you think, GMap is not disposed after `Dispose` call?

Comment: @Backs because when I use the memory profiler, I take a screenshot after I log out(when gmap is supposed to be disposed) and I still see an instance of gmap running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, `Dispose` does not mean, that object is removed from memory.
Dispose method just releases unmanaged resources.

.NET has managed memory. And Grbage Collector (GC), that [clears](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/) memory from unused objects.

You can force GC by using method [`GC.Collect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.8). But you sholdn't do it in real application. Let GC do it in the most suitable moment.

You can learn more from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0G5X3bu6hY).

Comment: There should be no need to call `GC.Collect()` though. Let the garbage collector take care of releasing memory.

Comment: The thing is that even if I force it, it stay open.

Comment: @ZacaryC waht is open? Read more about generations. If you want to check - call `Collect` 2-3 times.

Comment: @Backs I mean the instance X and Gmap stay open. There's not release. At this point I have minimal code juste a class déclaration and a show dialog, thats it and something is still holding it...

Comment: @Backs I just found out that if I change my .showDialog() to .show() it "solve the problem". The problem is that I use showDialog on purpose since I want it to be a modal form.